# How do i edit a record but show existing value selected of a drop-down box

Tags: django, django-queryset, dropdown

models.py

```
class Products(models.Model):
Name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Name of Product')
Category = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Product Category')
Description = models.CharField(max_length=220, verbose_name='Product Description')


class Categories(models.Model):
Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Category Title')
Description = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Category Description')
Picture = models.ImageField(default='/gifts.png', upload_to='ffff/')

def __str__(self):
    return self.Title
```

forms.py

```
class EditProduct(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Products
    fields = ['Name', 'Category', 'Description', 'Weight', 'Size', 'Cost', 'Personalised', 'Keywords',
              'Picture1']
    widgets = {
        'Category': Select(),
        }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditProduct, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Category'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all().order_by('Title'))
```

I've created records in models.py Categories (eg Title = 1, Title, 2, Title =3)
In models.py Products i have created some records (eg Name=Hat, Category=1; Name=Cap, Category=3)

I can add Product records easily with crispy forms and my drop down list appears for Category, select the choice and form saves. All works great

But when i try to EDIT the record, i use instance= and it brings the contents of the record back, but i also want a drop down list for category in the edit section, but if i put a drop-down list in, then it doesn't populate that field with existing value, i need to reselect it

My views.py

```
def products_edit(request, item_id):
pp = Products.objects.get(id=item_id)
my_form = EditProduct(instance=pp)
if 'first' in request.POST:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_form = EditProduct(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=pp)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            my_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Thank you the Product has been amended!')
            return redirect('frontpage-products')
context = {
    'my_form': my_form,
    'results': Products.objects.all().order_by('Name')
}
return render(request, 'frontpage/products_edit.html', context)
```

and my html

```
    <form method="POST" class="form-section" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="page_font search">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Edit Product</legend>
            {{ my_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="first">UPDATE</button>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

How do i populate the drop-down list with existing value?

Comment: If the `Products.Category` field was a `ForeignKey` to the `Categories` model your forms would be a lot simpler and it makes sense from a data modelling POV

Comment: Firstly have a look at [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Variable names should be in `snake_case` (you break this convention in your models `Name`, etc.). Next Model names should be **Singular**. Next as Iain Shelvington mentions above you set `Category` as a `CharField` yet use it to maintain relationships, whereas a `ForeignKey` would have been the **proper choice**.